# Is it okay to mix tribes with cyberpunk?

Tags: genre, videogame, flow

I am trying to write a story for an upcoming game, its theme is cyberpunk.

My problem is that I haven't written any long, complicated story before.

I've read many books and blogs, and watched a ton of vlogs, but I don't fully understand the complexities of cyberpunk.

After seeing a pin of a tribal-looking robot on pinterest, I got sold to the idea of tribes merging with machines, and having some of them despise machines, but the problem is the flow of events.

I couldn't figure out a way to mix he two -tribes and cyberpunk- together, because logically the tribes wouldn't even try to interact with the modern cyber society, and if they do it's probably going to be in some sort of war (They would even build walls to prevent machines from getting in), so an arrangement of a good flow of events is impossible (for me at least).

I have started to think that this isn't going to work. Any help or resources for a better understanding of cyberpunk is appreciated.

Comment: I understand what "cyberpunk" means, but I do not know what "tribes" is suppose to mean.

Comment: Well, some tribes do not want to interact with modern societies. Some want and you could see that looking for the history of Africa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because logically the tribes wouldn't even try to interact with the modern cyber society

Why is this logically obvious? It isn't, being honest. Tribal societies, when faced with a large technological empires, can either fight them and win (remaining autonomous), fight them and lose (being destroyed), or join the empire.

This happened numerous times in the colonial times of America. Many genocides occurred, but tribes like the Cherokee interacted with the Europeans and in many ways became part of their society. Pre-war of independence and pre-manifest destiny, more than a few tribes were willing to deal with and adopt some european customs.

Then manifest destiny screwed them over and reservations became a thing, but this interaction between tribal peoples and empires is quite common. As such, several tribes would be happy to adopt cyberpunk tech, I'd say.

Comment: You've made your point. But, what if they didn't win nor lose, I mean what if they had something that gave them almost equal power to the empire?

Comment: Then they remain autonomous (de facto like winning) or they trade culture (like a low-key version of imperial assimilation)

Comment: "can either fight them and win" this is only possible if a big tribe attacks small colony. But then a counterattack can make the tribe lose.

Comment: @rus9384 Didn't say the possibility was likely, just that it was one XD